# Stop Word Breaks using CSS on iPhones

Tags: iphone, html, css

I have Html

```
  <div class="callout-container req-text dark-callout">
       <div class="col-md-12 callout-description">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </div>
    </div>
```

And css

```
 @media (max-width: 500px){
   .callout-container {
        max-width: 300px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
}

.dark-callout .callout-description {
       color: #fff;
       font-size: 28px;
       font-weight: bold;
 }
```

It's ok on mobile devices, but if I use Iphone 6 or 7 I get this:

lorem Ipsum lorem Ip-

sum ...

I get "Ip-sum" only using Iphone. Is it possible to stop Word Breaks on Iphone using css ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a CSS media query to target mobile devices. For example:

```
@media only screen (max-device-width : 667px) {
  .callout_container {
    word-break:keep-all;
  }
}
```

See: [Stop Word Breaks in CSS on iOS Mobile Safari iPhones iPads](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/stop-hyphens-css-ios-mobile-safari-iphones/)

Answer (score 1):

Try `white-space:nowrap;` on `.callout_container`